# C++ function call with square brackets

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
int func(int n)
{
    return n;
}

int main()
{ 
    cout << func[4];
    cout << func[4, 3, 5];
}
```

What do these actually mean? I guess it is about accessing `func+4` and `func` is allocated space on calling `func[4]`.

But, `func[4, 3, 5]` is just absurd.

Comment: If you are using gcc or clang, I would recommend turning on `-Wall` which emits a warning here

Comment: actually I wanted to know more about the concept than handling the issue. thanks

Comment: I think it's a bug that the compilers don't give any message by default. [expr.sub] says "The type `T` shall be a completely defined object type."

Comment: I don't think it means anything useful, and there is not much concept to know more about. Function name, `func` here, is a pointer (to the function). Using array `[]` after function pointer makes no sense, you can't have array of functions. I think (but I am not sure), that function "value" is always interpreted as a pointer, so unlike normal arrays, `func[4]` is actually also pointer to function (its type is, I mean). But it is not a valid pointer, so actually even creating it is technically speaking undefined behavior.

Comment: You may or may not be getting a warning about this. If you aren't, yuck. If you are, never ignore warnings. Warnings are the compiler telling you that It can convert the code into a program, but the program probably doesn't do what you want. Understand the warning and either fix it or confirm that it is the behaviour you want. If you want this behaviour, try to rewrite the code so that the warning is not emitted so that you don't have noise in the build output.

Answer (score 15):

The reason this code compiles and `func[4]` is not a syntax error is:

1.Function types can implicitly convert to pointers of the same type.
So, if we have code like this:

```
int f(int);

using func_t = int(*)(int);

void g(func_t);
```

we can write

```
g(f)
```

and aren't forced to write `g(&f)`. The `&`, taking us from type `int(int)` to `int(*)(int)` happens implicitly.

2.In C (and necessarily in C++ for compatibility) pointers are connected to arrays, and when `p` is a pointer `p[x]` is the same as `*(p + x)`. So `func[4]` is the same as `*(func + 4)`.

3.`*(p+x)` has the type of a function `int(int)`, but again can implicitly decay to a pointer type whenever necessary. So `*(func + 4)` can implicitly just be `(func + 4)`.

4.Pointers of any type are streamable to `std::cout`.

---

Note, that just because it isn't a syntax error doesn't mean it is valid. Of course it is undefined behavior, and as the compiler warning emitted by gcc and clang indicates, pointer arithmetic with a function pointer is generally wrong, because you cannot make an array of functions. The implementation places functions however it likes. (You can make an array of function pointers but that is something else entirely.)

---

Edit: I should correct myself -- this answer is not entirely correct. `func[4]` is not valid, because the pointer is not a pointer to an object type. @holyblackcat answer is correct, see his answer for reference in the standard.

This code should be ill-formed, and gcc only compiles it without an error because they are using a nonstandard extension by default. Clang and msvc correctly reject this code.

Comment: No, it's not UB. It's simply invalid C++. GCC with `-pedantic-errors` [emits](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd4f9c4e25fa433c) `error: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]`.

Comment: I think it is UB because when the compiler sees `*(f+ 4)` it is normally a promise to the compiler that the address f+4 contains a valid value of type `decltype(*(f+4))`. Since that isn't true you get UB no diagnostic required. (These warnings are just the compiler being nice to you but the standard doesn't require that a conforming implementation emits a warning here.) Its UB even if you don't ultimately "use" the value and instead immediately take its address again. This doesn't count as a discarded value expression. * ing a pointer is like a blood oath :)

Comment: For instance if you add e.g. null check after `std::cout << f[4]` I expect that a conforming compiler can drop null checks at `f+4` because you have implicitly starred this pointer, c.f. http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html?m=1

Comment: Nope, it's invalid C++. `operator+` [requires](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#1) the pointer operand to be a pointer to an *object type* (which functions pointers are not).

Comment: Thanks! So does this mean the program is ill formed and conforming compilers must reject it, so it is a defect that gcc and clang merely give a warning? I thought the possible status of a program is like, ill formed, well formed but with undefined behavior, implementation defined, and having well defined behavior. I remember that "ill formed no diagnostic required" is a thing, is that what you think is happening here?

Comment: Edit: I just saw your answer black cat, thanks, that is indeed probably the most correct answer here. I didn't realize that gcc had this extension

Answer (score 10):

I'm surprised no answer mentions it, but:

**The code in the question is simply not valid C++.**

It's [rejected](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PmCKU3) by Clang and MSVC with no flags. GCC rejects it with `-pedantic-errors`.

`a[b]` (in absence of operator overloading) is defined as `*(a + b)`, and the builtin operator `+` requires the pointer operand to be a pointer to an *object type* (which functions pointers are not).

> #### [[expr.add]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#1)
>
> ...either both operands shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type, or **one operand shall be a pointer to a completely-defined object type** and the other shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type.

(Emphasis mine.)

---

GCC compiles the code because [an extension allowing arithmetic on function pointer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html) is enabled by default.

Due to function-to-pointer decay, `func[4]` is treated as `&(&func)[4]`, which effectively means `&func + 4`, which (as the link explains) simply adds `4` to the numerical value of the pointer. Calling resulting pointer will most likely cause a crash or unpredicatble results.

`std::cout` doesn't have an overload of `<<` suitable for printing function pointers, and the best suitable overload the compiler is able to find is the one for printing `bool`s. The pointer gets converted to `bool`, and since it's non-null, it becomes `true`, which is then printed as `1`.

Lastly, `func[4,3,5]` has the same effect as `func[5]`, since in this context `,` is treated as an operator, and `x , y` is equal to `y`.

Answer (score 5):

Since it has not been mentioned yet: `func[3, 4, 5]` is identical to `func[5]` - the commas in there are the builtin [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) which evaluates the left hand side expression, discards it and then evaluates the right hand side expression. There is no function call happening here and the commas in the code are not delimiting function parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is about accessing the `func+4` which is not already defined, leading to a garbage value. So the compiler will indicate you with the following warning message.

```
hereProgram: In function 'int main()':
Program:7: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic
```